# How to store multiple parameters passed as POST in database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have passed JSON encoded parameters by POST which we have captured and decoded in another PHP file. I have used the following code to do that.

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = json_decode($entityBody, true);
```

I have passed the JSON encoded parameters as follows:

```
{
 "id": "5",
 "name": "abcd",
 "imei": "1234"
}
```

Actually the number of parameters I am passing by POST may be 15 to 20 which I am going to insert in a table i.e. each of them is a field in the table in mysql database. I am new to JSON and PHP. What method I know is that get value of each parameter after checking whether it is set like following:

```
if(isset($entityBody['id']))
   ...
elseif(isset(...))
   ...
```

It is clear there will be many if and else when there are many parameters. So is there any way so that I can store the parameters in table in more efficient way.  If anyone helps me in doing that I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode function to parse the json to an array or object.

```
$a = json_decode($entityBody);
$a->id;
```

refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Yes I did that. I think my question is not clear. I actually want to store the parameter values in the database in which case I have to extract each individual parameter value separately which is very laborious. So I want to know is there any one so that I can store the JSON encoded parameters in the table more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using prepared statements you could do something like this. Please note that you should consider how you implement something like this, and change it to suit your needs.

```
$json = '{"id": "5","name": "abcd","imei": "1234"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);

if (!count($array) > 0) {
  throw new Exception('No params set.');
}

$allowedKeys = array('id','name','imei'); // could be hard coded, or something like: SELECT * FROM yourdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = yourtable

$queryParams = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (in_array($key, $allowedKeys)) {
    $queryParams['keys'][] = $key;
    $queryParams['values'][] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($queryParams);
$query = 'INSERT INTO yourtable (' . implode(', ', $queryParams['keys']) . ') VALUES (?' . str_repeat(',?', count($queryParams['values'])-1) . ')';
print_r($query); // INSERT INTO yourtable (id, name, imei) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Then you can just execute it with the $queryParams['values'] as the values :)
There's however no need to insert "id" if you're using auto increment, it will possibly just end up in some strange errors.

Comment: But according to your answer I have to create the array containing names of all the fields. So I am asking is there any alternative way to do that. Because the method you have suggested is error prone as one or more field names may be missed.

Comment: I have an alternative in the code, you could fetch all column names from the DB. What field names do you mean "may be missed"?

Comment: Could you please specify the syntax? Because I am trying it with the following statement as follows: $allowedKeys = array(SELECT * FROM blacbox_prod.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "test_table"); But it is not working.

Comment: No, two reasons for it not working. One, the array syntax you have written is not valid. The string I pasted was a sql-query, and must be sent to the database. The result from the database will be the array you want. Second, I got the syntax wrong, sorry about that ^^
This should work SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table';